# Access SQL - How to get the latest record and the last before timestamp?

Tags: sql, ms-access

since I'm not that good in SQL I decided to make my first time posting here, because I stuck with creating a query for a few days and couldn't figure out how to make it properly.
I have a table, which is holding information in a historical form to keep previous states of IP addresses with ports according to they timestamp.
My Java program is using this table, to handle the status of the IP addresses.
Additionally I need to show the last before ACTION DATE as last occurrence when the status changed for any ip address.

```
DST IP         | DST PORT | ACTION DATE         | STATUS
-------------------------------------------------------
0.0.0.0        |  80      | 2014.06.12. 9:22:27 | 4
10.146.203.184 |  80      | 2014.06.10. 8:43:51 | 4
10.146.203.184 |  80      | 2014.06.10. 8:43:41 | 4
10.146.203.184 |  80      | 2014.06.10. 8:28:35 | 0
```

I need to filter the table to show the unique IP addresses according to they latest status.

I can do that:

```
SELECT 
    T1.[DST IP], T1.[DST PORT], MAX(T1.[ACTION DATE]) AS LASTDATE 
FROM 
    IP_BLOCK_LIST AS T1 
GROUP BY 
    T1.[DST IP], T1.[DST PORT]
```

but I also need to show the last before ACTION DATE for the given IP and port as LAST OCCURRENCE. So I should get something like this of the above:

```
DST IP       | DST PORT  | ACTION DATE         | STATUS | **LAST OCCURRENCE** 

0.0.0.0        |80       | 2014.06.12. 9:22:27 | 4      | 2014.06.12. 9:22:27 

10.146.203.184 |80       | 2014.06.10. 8:43:51 | 4      | 2014.06.10. 8:43:41
```

I have the way to get the last before record from a table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ACTION DATE]
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM IP_BLOCK_LIST ORDER BY [ACTION DATE] DESC)  AS T3
ORDER BY T3.[ACTION DATE]
```

but not for each latest occurred ip-port.

It would be great to get some help, since it's killing me to figure out.

Thank you.

Istvan

Update

I finally came up with this query:

`SELECT T1.[DST IP], T1.RANGE, T1.[DST PORT], T1.STATUS, T1.NOTE, T1.SOURCE, T1.[BLOCK DIRECTION], T1.[ACTION DATE] AS [PERFORM DATE], Q1.[LAST OCCURRENCE]
FROM IP_BLOCK_LIST AS T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT Q2.[DST IP], Q2.[DST PORT], Max(Q2.[ACTION DATE]) AS [MaxOfACTION DATE], Min(Q2.[ACTION DATE]) AS [LAST OCCURRENCE] FROM (SELECT T2.[DST IP], T2.[DST PORT], T2.[ACTION DATE] FROM IP_BLOCK_LIST AS T2 WHERE (T2.[ACTION DATE]) In (SELECT TOP 2 T3.[ACTION DATE] FROM IP_BLOCK_LIST AS T3  WHERE T2.[DST IP] = T3.[DST IP] AND T2.[DST PORT] = T3.[DST PORT]  ORDER BY [ACTION DATE] DESC ))  AS Q2 GROUP BY Q2.[DST IP], Q2.[DST PORT])  AS Q1 ON (T1.[DST PORT] = Q1.[DST PORT]) AND (T1.[DST IP] = Q1.[DST IP])
WHERE (T1.[ACTION DATE]=[Q1].[MaxOfACTION Date])`

Can it be simplified a little bit?

Comment: Could you provide a script to generate your `IP_BLOCK_LIST` table and some data so we can help you even better?

Comment: Unfortunately the information what I have to work with is classified, since I working in IT security and I'm not allowed to give out too many details. The thing is, every time I set a new block status of an IP in the java program, it will create a new line with a current timestamp in the IP_BLOCK_LIST table.
Than it will display all recorded IP addresses with they status having the latest timestamp. Additionally I need to display the last before occurrence  next to each record I have from the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a correlated subquery:

```
select bl.*
from ip_block_list bl
where bl.[ACTION DATE] in (select top 2 bl2.[ACTION DATE]
                           from ip_block_list bl
                           where bl2.[DST IP] = bl.[DST IP] and
                                 bl2.[DST PORT] = bl.[DST PORT]
                           order by [ACTION DATE] desc
                          );
```

Note that in the case of ties, this will return more than two records for a given IP.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your quick answer. 
It seems promising, I think I'll have to put this one to a sub query to bring it onto the desired form to feed the JTable in my java application. I try to find out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join the subquery. **I don't know if this is the best solution, I just combined your queries into one query**.

```
SELECT 
    T1.[DST IP], T1.[DST PORT], MAX(T1.[ACTION DATE]) As ACTIONDATE, MAX(T3.[ACTION DATE]) AS LASTDATE 
FROM 
    IP_BLOCK_LIST AS T1 
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT TOP 1 
_sub.[ACTION DATE], _sub.[DST IP]
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 [ACTION DATE], [DST IP] FROM IP_BLOCK_LIST) AS _sub) 
AS T3 ON T1.[DST IP] = T3.[DST IP]
GROUP BY 
T1.[DST IP], T1.[DST PORT]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort as well,
I also looking for a way link the two queries, however your
query not really bringing the expected results.
Since my native is not English, I'm not sure I was specific enough to describe my problem.

Comment: Your question was clear, but maybe the stated queries in your question are not. Please provide a set of data so I can help you better.

Comment: If you look at my second query for the last before timestamp value, it is only applies to the whole table, not for each unique IP-Port.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to put the "last before" query to loop through each IP address returned from the first filtering query, since it only returns one record from the whole table.